# Veeam and physical servers

Tags: backup, veeam

Is it possible to create the backups from physical servers via Veeam software? Any experiences?
I know that the Veeam is good for creating backup from VMs, but how about physical servers?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Veeam has had support for physical server backup in the last few releases.

This is [detailed here](https://www.veeam.com/backup-management-tool-vm-physical-cloud.html) on Veeam's product page and is accomplished by an OS-based agent.

In my experiences, it works well, but I have fewer and fewer physical servers to back up separately now, so it's not a prominent feature for my environments.

Answer (score 2):

sure, Veeam has agents (Windows and linux) for physical server
I personaly configured it for physical servers bakcup and it works just fine

[Veeam Agent for Windows](https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/agentforwindows/userguide/overview.html?ver=50)

And

[Veeam Agent for linux](https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/agentforlinux/userguide/overview.html?ver=50)

Best regards